# how can i get the latest record in database based on datetime by comparing 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables say one with the code and its corresponding display name and another table with its results and its history.

**table 1:**

```
code    name

101 provide

102 modify

103 cease

104 cancel
```

**table 2:**

```
   code      result      environment     date            time

101  Pass        test           16/08/2019  06:19:35

102  Pass        acc            15/08/2019  06:19:35

101  Pass        test           16/08/2019  07:19:35

103  Fail        test           14/08/2019  06:19:35

102  Pass        test           12/08/2019  10:19:35

104  Pass        acc            13/08/2019  20:19:35
```

I would like to pick the most recent record specific to an environment & code and display as follows,

```
 code    name    result          date            time

101  provide     Pass           16/08/2019  06:19:35

102  modify      Pass           12/08/2019  10:19:35

103  cease       Fail           14/08/2019  06:19:35
```

I am pretty new to MSSQL.

Could you please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query would give you desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT  code, name , environment, result , [date], [time]
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY environment, Code ORDER BY [Date] desc, [Time] desc) rn
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.code=t2.code
    ) AS T 
Where T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t2.code, t2.name , t2.result , t2.date, t2.time

        ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY t2.environment, t2.code ORDER BY date desc, time desc) rn
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.code=t2.code
)

SELECT
    *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```